# Images with the same resolution, same pixel quantity but one is 3X larger than the other

Tags: image, canvas, jpeg

I'm processing two images from a HTML5 canvas, exporting it into a base64 using toDataUrl() and generating those images files, they have the same amount of pixels and same resolution, but one image file has 3x size than the other one.

Here is the Small sized image(1MB):
[image]

And here is the one with big size(3MB):
[image]

As you can see, the only difference is the black dots in the grid.

Here are the image magick's indentify verbose output.
To the non-dotted image:

```
Image: pontoSem.jpg
Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
Mime type: image/jpeg
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 1805x1520+0+0
Resolution: 72x72
Units: PixelsPerInch
Type: TrueColor
Endianess: Undefined
Colorspace: sRGB
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
  red: 8-bit
  green: 8-bit
  blue: 8-bit
Channel statistics:
  Pixels: 2743600
  Red:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 239.227 (0.938144)
    standard deviation: 50.1041 (0.196486)
    kurtosis: 9.08055
    skewness: -3.19968
  Green:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 241.654 (0.947662)
    standard deviation: 44.0232 (0.17264)
    kurtosis: 9.84544
    skewness: -3.28708
  Blue:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 239.038 (0.937403)
    standard deviation: 50.3878 (0.197599)
    kurtosis: 8.93501
    skewness: -3.18354
Image statistics:
  Overall:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 239.973 (0.94107)
    standard deviation: 48.2611 (0.189259)
    kurtosis: 9.42491
    skewness: -3.24166
Rendering intent: Perceptual
Gamma: 0.454545
Chromaticity:
  red primary: (0.64,0.33)
  green primary: (0.3,0.6)
  blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
  white point: (0.3127,0.329)
Background color: white
Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
Matte color: grey74
Transparent color: black
Interlace: None
Intensity: Undefined
Compose: Over
Page geometry: 1805x1520+0+0
Dispose: Undefined
Iterations: 0
Compression: JPEG
Quality: 100
Orientation: Undefined
Properties:
  date:create: 2017-03-02T16:56:35-03:00
  date:modify: 2017-03-02T16:52:35-03:00
  jpeg:colorspace: 2
  jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
  signature: 23b092dd21773df0a63a3fffe8241f9916354e3d29638979d672e9cb91026c25
Artifacts:
  filename: pontoSem.jpg
  verbose: true
Tainted: False
Filesize: 1.063MB
Number pixels: 2.744M
Pixels per second: 45.73MB
User time: 0.040u
Elapsed time: 0:01.060
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-02-22
```

And here is the identify to the largest image (the dotted one)

```
Image: pontoCom.jpg
Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
Mime type: image/jpeg
Class: DirectClass
Geometry: 1805x1520+0+0
Resolution: 72x72
Print size: 25.0694x21.1111
Units: PixelsPerInch
Type: TrueColor
Endianess: Undefined
Colorspace: sRGB
Depth: 8-bit
Channel depth:
  red: 8-bit
  green: 8-bit
  blue: 8-bit
Channel statistics:
  Pixels: 2743600
  Red:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 239.227 (0.938144)
    standard deviation: 50.1041 (0.196486)
    kurtosis: 9.08055
    skewness: -3.19968
  Green:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 241.654 (0.947662)
    standard deviation: 44.0232 (0.17264)
    kurtosis: 9.84544
    skewness: -3.28708
  Blue:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 239.038 (0.937403)
    standard deviation: 50.3878 (0.197599)
    kurtosis: 8.93501
    skewness: -3.18354
Image statistics:
  Overall:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 255 (1)
    mean: 239.973 (0.94107)
    standard deviation: 48.2611 (0.189259)
    kurtosis: 9.42491
    skewness: -3.24166
Rendering intent: Perceptual
Gamma: 0.454545
Chromaticity:
  red primary: (0.64,0.33)
  green primary: (0.3,0.6)
  blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
  white point: (0.3127,0.329)
Background color: white
Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
Matte color: grey74
Transparent color: black
Interlace: None
Intensity: Undefined
Compose: Over
Page geometry: 1805x1520+0+0
Dispose: Undefined
Iterations: 0
Compression: JPEG
Quality: 100
Orientation: Undefined
Properties:
  date:create: 2017-03-02T16:56:35-03:00
  date:modify: 2017-03-02T16:52:35-03:00
  jpeg:colorspace: 2
  jpeg:sampling-factor: 2x2,1x1,1x1
  signature: 23b092dd21773df0a63a3fffe8241f9916354e3d29638979d672e9cb91026c25
Artifacts:
  filename: pontoSem.jpg
  verbose: true
Tainted: False
Filesize: 1.063MB
Number pixels: 2.744M
Pixels per second: 45.73MB
User time: 0.040u
Elapsed time: 0:01.060
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-02-22
```

I just would like to know why the add of some black dots triple the file size, because they have the same number of pixels, and the sape dpi resolution.
Thanks in advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jpeg format uses some clever tricks to reduce image size with respect to a raw bitmap image. Those techniques have different success depending on the particular image being represented and generally work better when there are no sharp differences between pixels that are close together. The black dots on white background are exactly the kind of thing that makes it difficult.

In the first image, lots of space can be described as "this area is all white" while the second one needs a much longer description mentioning the color of each pixel wherever those black pixels are near, which is almost everywhere

Answer (score 1):

It's due to compression, the white squares on the first image is much more easily compressed than the second image with more randomness, as the image descriptor says it's using JPEG compression.
As most part of the surface area is using this background, it can easily impact in overall size as it compromises the compression algorithm efficiency.